# Find the closest point along a rectangle, given an another point and direction

Tags: mathematics, geometry

Given a rectangle, and a point with a vector direction towards the rectangle.
How can I find the closest point on the outside of that rectangle to the point in question?

[image: Point Facing Rectangle]

Comment: Can you explain more what you're asking? I'm really not getting it.

Comment: Let's say I have a character facing an object (a rectangle), and I draw an imaginary line from that character to the rectangle. I would like to know how I can tell which point along the outside of the rectangular object the line is touching.

Comment: They keyword to look up in Google is "AABB" (axis-aligned bounding box). If your "box" (rectangle) isn't axis-aligned yet, a simple transformation matrix - used on all items you care about, obviously - can be used first to change it into one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One technique which you could use is called "ray casting". It is commonly used for rendering graphics, but has other applications such as line-of-sight (as you are wanting to do) and path-finding. In general terms it works by finding the intersection of a ray and an object. In your example the ray is the vector for the character's direction.

A useful reference for ray/object intersections (and incidentally other object/object intersections) is [www.realtimerendering.com/intersections.html](http://www.realtimerendering.com/intersections.html) (look under the references for ray/aabb and ray/obb).

Answer (score 9):

The rectangle has four sides.  Each side is a line segment.

Test each of the four sides for intersection with the ray.  Track the closest hit.

Here's some code to find out where on the segment the ray hits:

```
bool intersect(const ray& ray, const segment& segment,point& hit) {
    // where do we intersect this line?
    float t = ((ray.direction.x * ray.origin.y + ray.direction.y *
        (segment[0].x - ray.origin.x)) -
        (ray.direction.x * segment[1].y)) /
        (ray.direction.y * (segment[0].x + segment[1].x) -
        ray.direction.x * (segment[0].y + segment[1].y));
    if(t >= 0.0 && t<=1.0) { // in the segment
        hit = segment[0] + (segment[1]-segment[0]*t);  // lerp
        return true;
    }
    return false; // no hit
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your box is axis aligned, you just have to clamp each coordinate axis to the box if the point is outside the box.

From RTCD pg 130:

```
// Do this for all 3 axes
if( point.x < min.x )  point.x = min.x ;
else if( point.x > max.x )  point.x = max.x ;
```

If you do this for x, y, z axes, then the `point` will be slammed to the nearest wall of the box, *if* it is outside the box to begin with.  if it is already inside the box, it will be left alone (where it is).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use just linear algebra (analytic geometry, to be more specific) to solve this. It depends on how you modeled the rectangle.

Here's a general case:
http://paulbourke.net/geometry/lineline2d/